# Notify.js with rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a simple notification template. I just want to apply a notification alert in my page. Not for button click, I need to show it after sign in / sign out events like that. I found a library which is very simple. [Here is the link](http://msroot.github.io/Notify.js/)

I used it's styles and load it. **It display correctly but jquery functions are not working.** Here is my code for template

```
<% if !flash.nil? %>
    <div class="alert-wrapper">
      <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <div id="notifications" class="alert alert-success alert-<%= name %>" role="alert"><%= msg %></div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

JS file

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
  Notify = function(text, callback, close_callback, style) {

var time = '10000';
var $container = $('#notifications');
var icon = '<i class="fa fa-info-circle "></i>';

if (typeof style == 'undefined' ) style = 'warning'

var html = $('<div class="alert alert-' + style + '  hide">' + icon +  " " + text + '</div>');

$('<a>',{
  text: '×',
  class: 'button close',
  style: 'padding-left: 10px;',
  href: '#',
  click: function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    close_callback && close_callback()
    remove_notice()
  }
}).prependTo(html)

$container.prepend(html)
html.removeClass('hide').hide().fadeIn('slow')

function remove_notice() {
  html.stop().fadeOut('slow').remove()
}

var timer =  setInterval(remove_notice, time);

$(html).hover(function(){
  clearInterval(timer);
}, function(){
  timer = setInterval(remove_notice, time);
});

html.on('click', function () {
  clearInterval(timer)
  callback && callback()
  remove_notice()
});


}
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: So, what's the exact problem? It is not displaying or only the first one displays, etc.? PS. You have more than one `'#notifications` element. ID's should be unique.

Comment: Working it's styles. But not working jquery functions. The notification alert appearing and staying in current page.